# CSS background opacity turns gray and covers image on mobile only

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is the goal. Screenshot is taken from Desktop on Google Chrome:
[image]

However that is not what it looks like on mobile. Shrinking the window size on desktop also gives the correct result, so I'm guessing it's not a matter of screen size, but platform. This is on a wordpress site, and the html for that section is:

```
<div id="athena-page-jumbotron" class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)) ?>">
```

The CSS to get that effect is:

```
#athena-page-jumbotron {
 width: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: rgba( 0,0,0,0.4 ); // this is what gives it the opacity
}
```

However on mobile it looks like this:
[image]

You can see that the dark overlay is missing, which makes the text hard to read.
To try to solve the issue, I added additional rules to enforce the opacity for the overlay

```
#athena-page-jumbotron {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
}
```

However this results in the following effect, which is undesirable:
[image]

As you can see, the overlay is still missing but there is a gray box. Changing the CSS to `background-color` instead of `background` reverts it back to the original. Changing the opacity from 0.4 to 1 changes the gray box to black, and changing it to 0 makes the box white. Also adding a `@media` tag for the resolution doesn't help much.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with linear-gradient.

```css
.tinted-image {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height:200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: 
    /* top, transparent red */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    url(https://blogs.office.com/en-us/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/06/June-updates-to-Get-and-Transform.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="tinted-image">
  about us
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know you could put a linear-gradient and image on the same element.

Comment: Yeah. its pretty cool! hope you got what you were looking for.

Comment: i put linear-gradient in there.. Still a gray box, can you confirm that this is designed to work on mobile as well? I'm using safari on an iPhone 8

Comment: @behdad so I discovered that it works if I manually add in the url for the bottom image. However I want to keep the image to remain dynamic, letting it use the image-url that is provided in the data-image-src property. I can't use this solution since the image is different on different pages.

Comment: @LukePatterson Not sure how this is being rendered or what the full html output is, but did you try absolute positioning another div over the image with the css you mentioned earlier `background: rgba( 0,0,0,0.4 );` ?

Comment: @LukePatterson, sorry for answering late. I think you can do position absolute too. you can have a main div with position relative and inside that main div you can have another div with position absolute with top,left, bottom and right equal to 0, this will put the child div on top of the main div, then you can add opacity or linear-gradient to that. Remember that you should have the background picture on the main div.